# Как сверстать такой квадрат?

Tags: html, css, svg

подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сверстать такой блок c квадратом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.square {
  width: 441px;
  height: 441px;
  background: red;
  border: 18px dashed #3B3838;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  
</div>
```

Comment: [Control the dashed border stroke length and distance between strokes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2771171/2881286)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Можно так, чтобы оставить элемент прозрачным:

```css
.square {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-image:linear-gradient(45deg, 
    black 0%, black 10%,
    transparent 10%, transparent 40%,
    black 40%, black 60%, 
    transparent 60%, transparent 90%, 
    black 90%, black 100%) 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

### Для разнообразия, решение SVG

С графикой должен работать SVG, для этого он и создан.
Всего одна строка кода svg - `<rect .... />` и квадрат с уголками создан:

```css
.container {
width:75vw;
height:75vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 350 350" style="background:#eee"  >  
<rect x="25" y="25" width="300" height="300" stroke-dasharray="100,200" stroke-dashoffset="50"  fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="6"/>
</svg>     
</div>
```

Длина одной стороны квадрата - 300px.
Выбираем длину уголка - 100px
Расстояние между уголками получается - 200px
Отсюда получается формула `stroke-dasharray="100,200"`
Сдвигаем линию на половину длины уголка `stroke-dashoffset="50"`

### Варианты анимации

- Перемещение уголка в соседний угол прямоугольника

Расстояние между начальными точками соседних уголков - `300px`, поэтому перемещаем их в анимации `stroke-dashoffset "values="50;-250"`  на 300px

```css
.container {
width:30vw;
height:30vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 350 350" style="background:#eee"  >  
<rect x="25" y="25" width="300" height="300" stroke-dasharray="100,200" stroke-dashoffset="50"  fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="6">
 <animate id="an" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click;an.end+0.5s" dur="1.5s" values="50;-250" calcMode="linear" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" />
</rect>
</svg>  
</div>
```

- Перемещение уголков туда-обратно

`values="50;-250;-250;50;50"` - повторение параметров обеспечивает паузы в конечных точках анимации.

```css
.container {
width:30vw;
height:30vh;
}

<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 350 350" style="background:#eee"  >
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 350 350" style="background:#eee"  >  
         

<rect x="25" y="25" width="300" height="300" stroke-dasharray="100,200" stroke-dashoffset="50"  fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="6">
 <animate id="an" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click;an.end+1.5s" dur="6s" values="50;-250;-250;50;50" calcMode="linear" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" />
</rect>
</svg>
</div>
```

### Изображение внутри уголков + анимация

При fill="none" квадрат  прозрачен и становится видна картинка

```css
.container {
width:40vw;
height:40vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 350 350" style="background:#eee"  >  
          <!-- Изобраение пингвина -->
<image xlink:href="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f427.svg" y="25" x="5" width="98%" height="85%" />
<rect x="25" y="25" width="300" height="300" stroke-dasharray="100,200" stroke-dashoffset="50"  fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="6">
 <animate id="an" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click;an.end+0.5s" dur="1.5s" values="50;-250" calcMode="linear" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" />
</rect> 
 
</svg>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
.square {
  --bg-line-h: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #000 33%, transparent 33%, transparent 67%, #000 67%);
  --bg-line-v: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000, #000 33%, transparent 33%, transparent 67%, #000 67%);
  width: 75vmin; height: 75vmin;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10vmin auto; padding: 2vmin;
  background: top left / 100% 1vmin var(--bg-line-h),
              bottom left / 100% 1vmin var(--bg-line-h),
              top left / 1vmin 100% var(--bg-line-v),
              top right / 1vmin 100% var(--bg-line-v);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #f002;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Тут размер квадрата, его отступы, и толщина линий сделаны респонсивными (подстраиваются к размерам вьюпорта) - если этого не требуется, то просто замени `vmin`-величины на их аналоги в абсолютных единицах, например в `px`.